# Trying to add Rx460 graphics driver to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

My question is about AMD drivers for Ubuntu 17.10.  I've tried everything to install an AMD RX460 driver so that my computer stops freezing but it shut down my computer and I had to uninstall.  Does anyone have a proper walkthrough so that I am able to succeed?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0L_85Xgd1Aw) is a video that shows you how to install the drivers.

[Here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx) is a link to the page. Scroll down and choose your distribution.

In short:

- Download the driver
- Extract the archive
- Run the installer

I hope this helps.